# How to create Categorical from UInt32Type and RevMapping in Rust polars

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I can get integer representation and revmap of CategoricalChunked.

```
let s = Series::new("Fruit", ["Apple", "Apple", "Pear"]);
let s_cat = s.cast(&DataType::Categorical(Some(Arc::new(RevMapping::default())))).unwrap();
let s_cat_chunck = s_cat.categorical().unwrap().to_owned(); //CategoricalChunked

let s_logical = s_cat_chunck.logical().to_owned(); // integer representation
let s_revmap = s_cat_chunck.get_rev_map().to_owned(); //revmap
```

How to create CategoricalChunked from `s_logical` and `s_revmap`?

Context:

I need to do some operations (mostly comparisons and if else branching based on comparsions) on elements of a CategoricalChunked. The CategoricalChunked is large and there will be very large number of comparisons in my algorithm.
To iterate over CategroicalChunked we have function `iter_str()`. But the iterator iterate over &str. My guess is comparisons on &str would be slower. I am thinking of doing comparisons with integer representation (`s_logical`) and get result back as categorical.