# How do I cast to Categorical in Polars in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

Given the following Rust function:

```rust
pub fn test_dataframe() -> PolarsResult<DataFrame> {
    let df = df! {
        "lo" => [...],
        "hi" => [...],
        "register" => [...],
    }?;
    df.lazy().select([
        col("lo")
            .map_many(
                decode_to_str,
                &[col("hi")],
                GetOutput::from_type(DataType::Utf8),
            )
            .cast(DataType::Categorical(None)) // <-- Here!
            .alias("categorical_1"),
        col("register")
            .map(
                register_names_from_register_ids,
                GetOutput::from_type(DataType::Utf8),
            )
            .cast(DataType::Categorical(None)) // <-- And here!
            .alias("categorical_2"),
    ]).collect()
}
```

I have a couple of options for how to instantiate the `DataType` enum in the calls to `.cast()`.

1. Calling it with `DataType::Categorical(None)` as exemplified [here.](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/docs/performance/index.html#example-lazy-join-multiple-dataframes-on-a-categorical)
2. Calling it with `DataType::Categorical(Some(Arc::new(RevMapping::default())))` as exemplified [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72899419/12117261)
3. Instantiating the `RevMapping` first and cloning it to the various `Categorical`s. I couldn't find an example of this online; please see the code below.

```rust
// ...
let revmap = Arc::new(RevMapping::default());
// ...
    .cast(DataType::Categorical(Some(revmap.clone()))
// ...
    .cast(DataType::Categorical(Some(revmap.clone()))
// ...
```

My question is: what's the recommended way of doing it? I was surprised to see the `Categorical(None)` option in the official docs, as I can't see any disadvantages in re-using the cache between different columns, but I might be way wrong. I couldn't find any specific recommendations towards one or the other in the official docs.

I tried getting the estimated size of the dataframe with all three options using `df.estimated_size()`, but the size wasn't affected by my swapping out the `RevMapping` or leaving it `None`.

Comment: I think that `Categorical(None)` with `enable_string_cache` is essentially the same as Option #3. I think the best docs are [here](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/fn.enable_string_cache.html). I don't think these options will affect the size of any one DataFrame, but rather will affect memory usage and maybe performance of the program as a whole.